# Two user one ticket

Tags: database, transactions

Recently on the interview I received a question: "What would happen when two different users will try to book the same ticket at the same millisecond?" 
Anyone knows the answer?

Comment: With a well designed system: one of them will get notified that the ticket is no longer available.

Comment: but which one if the made a reservation in the exact same time?